# meteor.js app running normaly on localhost but not on server

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have this app that seems to run normally on localhost but when I deployed it to meteor or digital ocean, then from sudden reason, no functionalities work...

Here is the screencast localy: http://screencast.com/t/tyD995EyM

Here is the current hosted version on meteor: cryptonic.meteor.com

And digital ocean: 104.236.90.81

Code repo on git if it helps... https://github.com/lklancir/cryptonic

Could anyone at least help me locate the problem or point in direction, no major console log errors...

I might be guessing that maybe some JS files are killing each other when composed in one single .js file on upload, but why does it work locally is the thing that bothers me

Comment: "no functionalities" so what do you get? A blank screen? An error page?

Comment: The  jquery scroll doesn't work, button click no event, can't save the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do see this error in the console on the meteor.com site...

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: gnMenu is not defined
```

I'm not completely sure, but I think it might be a file loading order. You have client/lib/custom.js which uses gnMenu from client/lib/gnmenu.js

Since all files in lib are loaded first, there might be a load order issue. Per the http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp page, the files should be loaded from lib in alphabetical order so this would be an issue as custom.js would be loaded first, but I do not know why it would work on local...

```
HTML template files are always loaded before everything else
Files beginning with main. are loaded last
Files inside any lib/ directory are loaded next
Files with deeper paths are loaded next
Files are then loaded in alphabetical order of the entire path
```

Comment: I finally managed to get it working... there was a problem with a custom.js file but no idea why it worked with it on local, and why not on server...